# Consuming Webservice in Flash CS4 - simple sample needed :-)

Tags: flash, web-services, cs4

I'm a beginner in Flash/AS and want to try if its possible to consume a webservice given back from a SAP BW system. Just want to see how the connection works and how I can access and use the returned data (guess its XML).

Found this sample [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200223073402/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/pakistan/archive/2005/04/28/38590.aspx) but its for MX2004 and things seem to have changed... (e.g. cant finde the "Web Service panel")

Can anybody give me a simple sample code how this is done?

Thanks a lot
Gerald

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the Cs4 Flash Data integration, it surely will help you get through this.

Cheers,

Ernani

Comment: Please let me know if you need this sample in AS2 or AS3. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Check this video.
You have to import some Flex components, because the WebService class was removed from Flash.
http://www.webkitchen.be/2009/03/02/video-tutorial-use-the-flex-webservice-component-in-flash-cs4-projects/